# Is this inference correct using the existential quantifier?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, axiom-of-choice

Suppose that one has the statement $\forall x\exists y :P(x,y)$. Given an $a$, then it follows that there is a $b$ such that $P(a,b)$.

**My question is**: Am I allowed to call this object $b_a$ or $b(a)$ or any other version that behaves like a function symbol? If so, why or why not?

**Why am I asking this?** Suppose that $X$ is a set and we have $\forall x \in X \exists y \in X: P(x,y)$ and suppose that we are allowed to introduce $b_a$ for the appropriate object as explained above. Then we know that there exists the set $A$ such that $$\forall z : z \in A \iff \exists a,b \in X : z=(a,b) \wedge =b_a$$ or in other words $$A=\{(a,b_a):a \in X\}.$$

If this were allowed, I wouldn't need the axiom of choice to construct the set $A$. However, if this wasn't allowed, I would need the axiom of choice, since I can't (or at least **I** don't know how to) construct such a set from the statement $\forall x \in X \exists y \in X:P(x,y)$. More precisely, I don't see how one could prove the existence of a set $A$ that consists of pairs of the elements $x$ of $X$ with exactly one element $y$ of $X$ that satisfy $P(x,y)$. If the object $y$ is unique, then this is easy: $$\forall z : z \in A \iff \exists x,y \in X: z=(x,y) \wedge P(x,y)$$ or $$A=\{(x,y) \in X \times X: P(x,y)\}$$
**One possible explanation?** I think in formal logic this is not allowed, but I am not sure how it is in more informal maths other than formal logic, or even why its not allowed in formal logic. One potential reason I came up with is the following. Suppose one has an object $x$ and introduces a function symbol $f(x)$ for an object $y$ that satisfies $P(x,y)$. Then, if $y_1,y_2$ are two objects that satisfy $P(x,y_1),P(x,y_2)$, one might be tempted to incorrectly infer: $P(x,y_1)$ implies $y_1=f(x)$ and $P(x,y_2)$ implies $y_2=f(x)$, thus $y_2=y_1$, where one used the intuition that function symbols should be unique objects, which they of course are not in this case. However, with enough caution, such mistakes shouldn't happen. Therefore I am not entirely sure why its not allowed to introduce those.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Im sorry I don't quite understand what you are agreeing or disagreeing with. Could you expand your comment?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I see that. But I am not sure how that relates to my question.

Comment: Together with Saving's answer, see also [Karagila's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/191013/152921) and [Schweber's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2176042/754923) concerning Skolemisation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a precise sense in which it is acceptable to do this even without any form of the axiom of choice.

Suppose we are working in first-order logic over vocabulary $V$. And suppose we have some set of axioms $T$ and some proposition $P(x, y)$ in the variables $x, y$, and we have $T \vdash \forall x \exists y P(x, y)$. Then we can define $V' = V \cup \{f\}$, where $f$ is a unary function symbol, and define $T' = T \cup \{\forall x P(x, f(x))\}$. Then this new deductive system is a conservative extension. More formally, for any sentence $\phi$ in the language of $V$, we have $T \vdash \phi$ if, and only if, $T' \vdash \phi$.

This can be proved even without using the axiom of choice, as it is purely a syntactic fact. However, it is more convenient to prove it using the axiom of choice and the completeness theorem. For if we have any $V$-structure $M$ such that $M \models T$, then we have $M \models \forall x \exists y P(x, y)$. We then apply the axiom of choice to produce some $f^M$ such that $\forall x \in M (P^M(x, y))$. Adding $f^M$ to $M$ gives us $M'$, which is a $V'$ structure which is a model of $T'$. And of course, for any sentence $\phi$ in the language of $V$, we have $M' \models \phi$ if and only if $M \models \phi$. Thus, we see that semantically, $T'$ is a conservative extension of $T$ - for all $\phi$ in the language of $V$, we see that $T \models \phi$ iff $T' \models \phi$. Apply the completeness theorem to get the syntactic version.

In fact, we only require the ultrafilter lemma to get that $T'$ is semantically a conservative extension of $T$. So this fact does not imply the axiom of choice. However, without the axiom of choice, we cannot, in general, take a model $M$ of $T$ and extend it to a model $M'$ of $T'$, where both models are exactly the same $V$-structure. Instead, what we see is that if $M$ is a $V$-structure modelling $T$ such that $M \models \neg \phi$, then there exists some $M'$ which is a model of $T'$ and of $\neg \phi$, but there is no reason to believe that $M$ and $M'$ should be nicely related to each other by being the same $V$-structure.

In particular, if we have $\forall x \in X \exists y \in X (P(x, y))$, then we have $X \models \forall x \exists y P(x, y)$. So if we wish to make deductions in first-order logic about $X$, we could, within the first-order system, add a function symbol $a \mapsto b_a$ and the axiom $\forall x (P(x, b_x))$. But (in the absence of the axiom of choice) this would not actually mean there exists such a function $X \to X$.

Comment: I don't understand everything you write because of my background. However, concerning your second paragraph especially, why is that allowed? I thought extension by definition only allows the introduction of a function symbol if the existence of the object is unique?

Comment: @user103178981 If you don’t understand why the claims made in the second paragraph are true, you should read the third paragraph, which proves them (at least assuming the axiom of choice). The proof without choice is a little bit more difficult, but it turns out that due to the properties of $\vdash$, you can reduce to the case where $V$ and $T$ are both finite; you can then use the fact that countable consistent theories have countable models. You are also correct that this process is not necessarily a definitional extension.

Comment: I dont know anything about models however, which is why this part is also hard to understand. I know of extension by definition and I know of the axiom of choice. I also know that the AOC essentially gives me a unique representative for each $x$, thus leading me to the $\forall \exists!$ case of definitorial extension, doesnt it? Isn't this roughly what is going on?